# Maven pulls unwanted dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm currently facing trouble with a Java project using Maven. I have a dependency in my pom pointing to version 1.4 of Apache's `commons-cli` like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Now during runtime I get a `NoSuchMethodException` because apparently, an older version of this library is being loaded into the classpath which lacks a certain method.

**But**, no other version is referenced in my project and `mvn dependency:tree` (with the verbose option!) does not list any other import of `commons-cli` besides the 1.4 version I explicitly use.

However, when I clear the repository in .m2 and run the maven install, I see that both version 1.0 and 1.2 of the commons-cli library are being pulled. What other reasons for pulling these dependencies can Maven have if they are not a transitive dependency of any import of mine?

Edit: Here is the full effective pom.

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated on 2018-05-23T06:35:53                                       -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project 'com.crawljax:crawljax-cli:jar:3.7-SNAPSHOT' -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.crawljax</groupId>
    <artifactId>crawljax-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.crawljax</groupId>
  <artifactId>crawljax-cli</artifactId>
  <version>3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Crawljax CLI</name>
  <description>The Crawljax command line interface</description>
  <url>http://crawljax.com/crawljax-cli</url>
  <inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>amesbah</id>
      <name>Ali Mesbah</name>
      <email>a.mesbah@gmail.com</email>
      <url>http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~amesbah/</url>
      <organization>SALTLab, UBC</organization>
      <organizationUrl>http://salt.ece.ubc.ca</organizationUrl>
      <timezone>-8</timezone>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>arie.van.deursen</id>
      <name>Arie van Deursen</name>
      <email>arie.vanDeursen@tudelft.nl</email>
      <url>http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~arie/</url>
      <organization>SWERL, TU Delft</organization>
      <organizationUrl>http://swerl.tudelft.nl</organizationUrl>
      <timezone>+1</timezone>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>alexnederlof</id>
      <name>Alex Nederlof</name>
      <email>alex@nederlof.com</email>
      <url>http://alex.nederlof.com</url>
      <organization>TU Delft</organization>
      <timezone>+1</timezone>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
      <name>Crawljax Mailing List</name>
      <subscribe>http://groups.google.com/group/crawljax/subscribe</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>crawljax+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com</unsubscribe>
      <post>crawljax@googlegroups.com</post>
      <archive>http://groups.google.com/group/crawljax</archive>
    </mailingList>
  </mailingLists>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:crawljax/crawljax.git/crawljax-cli</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:crawljax/crawljax.git/crawljax-cli</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/crawljax-cli</url>
  </scm>

  <issueManagement>
    <system>GitHub</system>
    <url>https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <ciManagement>
    <system>Jenkins</system>
    <url>http://jenkins.crawljax.com</url>
  </ciManagement>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
      <name>Nexus Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <properties>
    <arguments />
    <jetty.version>9.3.0.M1</jetty.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <metrics.version>3.0.2</metrics.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <selenium.version>3.0.0</selenium.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <sonatypeOssDistMgmtSnapshotsUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</sonatypeOssDistMgmtSnapshotsUrl>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.crawljax</groupId>
      <artifactId>crawljax-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.crawljax.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>crawloverview-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>18.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <directory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target</directory>
    <finalName>crawljax-cli-3.7-SNAPSHOT</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            <arguments> -Psonatype-oss-release</arguments>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.10</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z</dateFormat>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                <gitDescribe>
                  <always>true</always>
                  <abbrev>7</abbrev>
                  <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
                </gitDescribe>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z</dateFormat>
            <verbose>false</verbose>
            <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
            <gitDescribe>
              <always>true</always>
              <abbrev>7</abbrev>
              <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
            </gitDescribe>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>(,2.1.0),(2.1.0,2.2.0),(2.2.0,)</version>
                  <message>Maven 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 produce incorrect GPG signatures and checksums respectively.</message>
                </requireMavenVersion>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>zip-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/resources/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <goals>assembly:assembly</goals>
          <tagNameFormat>crawljax-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
          <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
          <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
          <arguments> -Psonatype-oss-release</arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                  <mainClass>com.crawljax.cli.JarRunner</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                  <mainClass>com.crawljax.cli.JarRunner</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.crawljax.cli.JarRunner</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <file>crawljax-cli-3.7-SNAPSHOT.zip</file>
              <packaging>zip</packaging>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <file>crawljax-cli-3.7-SNAPSHOT.zip</file>
          <packaging>zip</packaging>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z</dateFormat>
              <verbose>false</verbose>
              <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
              <gitDescribe>
                <always>true</always>
                <abbrev>7</abbrev>
                <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
              </gitDescribe>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z</dateFormat>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          <gitDescribe>
            <always>true</always>
            <abbrev>7</abbrev>
            <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
          </gitDescribe>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/roper/idp-business-logic/crawljax-mainline/crawljax/cli/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: First show the full pom file...

Comment: The pom you are using would be more helpful...

Comment: Can you give a reference to your Github project? Or is this one: https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax If so are we talking about master or a particular branch?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that the effective pom would be the best for a multi modular project like this as it definitely shows all dependencies involved. The project is in fact a fork of crawljax (https://github.com/Sekagra/crawljax/) precisely the branch "restart"

Comment: First I found a typo in web module where a reference to `<artifactId>gcommons-cli</artifactId>` instead `<artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>`....

Comment: Furthermore I found resulting `distribution.zip` contains commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar  and commons-lang-2.4.jar ...but only a single `commons-cli-1.4.jar`...Furthermore the cli modules only contains the `commons-cli-1.4.jar`....? How have you called maven to build all? `mvn clean package`? Furthermore there are several aspects of best practices in Maven violated....

Comment: Thx, fixed that but I haven't committed since, sorry. The easiest way to spot the phenomenon is by compiling (`mvn clean install -DskipTests`) the core project. The culprit that imports the old cli artifacts is somewhere there. I might want to add that the project is given to me as is and I'm trying to make adjustments to it, so I'm not familiar with the whole codebase yet.

Comment: I have simply build the whole project from root via `mvn clean package -DskipTests` and got not old versions of commons-cli only 1.4. as expected....

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem? BTW: Which Maven version do you use? Have done on plain command line?

Comment: Always tried it plainly on command line using Linux with a previously removed .m2 repo and using what is (I think) the most recent maven at version 3.5.3. The `clean` in maven should remove all leftovers in the target directory, but I might be at the point where I also try a fresh checkout.